# How to convert a bitmap picture/image in to a 1 bpp bitmap image in .net 4?

Tags: c#-4.0, bitmap, bit-manipulation

I am working on `Asp.Net mvc3` project. In the middle of my project I have to do this task.To convert a bitmap image in to only 1Bite per pixel format.

How to convert a `bitmap` picture/image into a 1 bpp bitmap image in `.net 4`?

Can any one give me any hint how to convert so?

Comment: Don't do it, it scales poorly and results are crappy.  Do it anyway with this kind of code: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/94dc2598-bc40-4170-8dcb-7215223d0fd3

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of that task depends on the source image: if it is black and white, then you should just need to create a new Bitmap with PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed and then call LockBits on both bitmaps and loop over each pixel. If it on the other hand contains many colors/levels of gray, then you need to dwell into dithering algorithms, like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering or find code that does this for you.